# Mutable borrow to function for struct holding reference issues

Tags: rust

I am having issues with a struct that I am passing around as a mutable reference. The issue only occurs when the struct is defined to hold a reference.

```rust
struct Global<'a> {
    one: i32,
    two: &'a i32
}

fn do_task<'a, F, R: 'a>(global: &'a mut Global<'a>, task: F)
    where F: Fn(&'a mut Global<'a>) -> &'a R {
    let result = task(global);
}

fn one<'a>(global: &'a mut Global<'a>) -> &'a i32 {
    &global.one
}

fn two<'a>(global: &'a mut Global<'a>) -> &'a i32 {
    global.two
}

fn main() {
    let number = 2;
    let mut global = Global {
        one: 1,
        two: &number
    };
    do_task(&mut global, one);
    do_task(&mut global, two);
}
```

The borrow checker complains with the following:

```
error: cannot borrow `global` as mutable more than once at a time
do_task(&mut global, two);
             ^~~~~~
note: previous borrow of `global` occurs here; the mutable borrow prevents subsequent moves, borrows, or modification of `global` until the borrow ends
do_task(&mut global, one);
             ^~~~~~
note: previous borrow ends here
fn main() {
...
}
^
```

But, if I change the code so that the field `two` is not a reference, like in the following example, then it passes.

```rust
struct Global {
    one: i32,
    two: i32,
}

fn do_task<'a, F, R: 'a>(global: &'a mut Global, task: F)
    where F: Fn(&'a mut Global) -> &'a R {
    let result = task(global);
}

fn one<'a>(global: &'a mut Global) -> &'a i32 {
    &global.one
}

fn two<'a>(global: &'a mut Global) -> &'a i32 {
    &global.two
}

fn main() {
    let mut global = Global {
        one: 1,
        two: 2
    };
    do_task(&mut global, one);
    do_task(&mut global, two);
}
```

I tried surrounding the `do_task` function calls with another scope, but it had no effect.

Why does having the reference extend the mutable borrow to the end of main, and is there any way around this?

I am using `rustc 1.0.0 (a59de37e9 2015-05-13) (built 2015-05-14)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you have accidentally tied together `Global`’s generic lifetime parameter with the lifetime of the mutable borrow.

When you require `&'a mut Global<'a>`, that means that the duration of the mutable borrow of the `Global` must be as long as the reference in `two`—thus, the full length of the `Global`’s existence. You have thus made what is inferred to be a permanent borrow of `global` when you write `&mut global`. I’ll write it this way in syntax that isn’t quite valid but gets the point across:

```rust
fn main() {
    'a: {
        let number: i32 + 'a = 2;
        let mut global: Global<'a> = Global {
            one: 1,
            two: &'a number,
        };
        do_task(&mut global: &'a mut Global<'a>, one);
        do_task(&mut global: &'a mut Global<'a>, two);
    }
}
```

Each `&mut global` is borrowing `global` until the end of the `'a` block, and so the second clashes with the first.

You wish to treat those two lifetimes separately. The function should, rather than using a concrete lifetime, bind a lifetime parameter: this is `F: for<'b> Fn(&'b mut Global) -> &'b R` read it like this: “`F` should, given an arbitrary lifetime `'b`, implement `Fn(&'b mut Global) -> &'b R`”. The actual functions are then written with the lifetime parameter to `Global` removed so it can be inferred as another arbitrary lifetime, like so:

```rust
fn one<'a>(global: &'a mut Global) -> &'a i32 {
    &global.one
}
```

[Here’s the final result:](http://is.gd/mnxt32)

```rust
struct Global<'a> {
    one: i32,
    two: &'a i32
}

fn do_task<F, R>(global: &mut Global, task: F)
where F: for<'a> Fn(&'a mut Global) -> &'a R {
    let result = task(global);
}

fn one<'a>(global: &'a mut Global) -> &'a i32 {
    &global.one
}

fn two<'a>(global: &'a mut Global) -> &'a i32 {
    global.two
}

fn main() {
    let number = 2;
    let mut global = Global {
        one: 1,
        two: &number
    };
    do_task(&mut global, one);
    do_task(&mut global, two);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a link to documentation on the `for<>` syntax? I couldn't find anything in the book, reference or RFCs.

Comment: @Dale, it is very possible that it is not documented in the book yet, but [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0387-higher-ranked-trait-bounds.md) is an RFC which introduced this syntax. It also explains the rationale behind it. It's called higher-ranked trait bounds, BTW.